# Authorize.net SIM method in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, authorize.net, coldfusion-8

I need to implement a payment process using the SIM method from Authorize.net in ColdFusion. After reading the documentation, played around with their sandbox account and also looked at the sample.cfm here is what I did for a test:

I have a donation form in my website where my users, among others, enter the amount they want to donate and also the program they want to support.

In the form tag of this donation page I put:

```
  <form method="post" name="givingform"  action="confirmation.cfm">
```

When the donation form get posted to confirmation.cfm there is an insert statement inserting users information including the amount of donation into my table in database.
There are two buttons in this page:

EDIT button    : For users to edit their information (basically a javascript back button)
   PAYMENT button : For showing Authorize.net credit card screen (see below).

So between the `<cfform> </cfform>` tags I have the form posted to Authorize's test URL:

```
 <cfset posturl="https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll">
 <CFFORM name="creditcard_form" action="#posturl#" method="POST">

 <cfset loginID="my login">
 <cfset transactionKey="my key">
 <cfset amount="19.99">
 <cfset description="Sample Transaction">
 <cfset label="Submit Payment"> 
 <cfset testMode="false">

 <cfif IsDefined("FORM.amount")>
   <cfset amount=FORM.amount>
 </cfif>
 <cfif IsDefined("FORM.description")>
   <cfset description=FORM.description>
 </cfif>
 <!--- check to see if the amount or description were sent using the GET method    --->
 <cfif IsDefined("URL.amount")>
   <cfset amount=URL.amount>
 </cfif>
 <cfif IsDefined("URL.description")>
   <cfset description=URL.description>
 </cfif>

 <!--- an invoice is generated using the date and time --->
 <cfset invoice=DateFormat(Now(),"yyyymmdd") & TimeFormat(Now(),"HHmmss")>
 <!--- a sequence number is randomly generated --->
 <cfset sequence=RandRange(1, 1000)>
 <!--- a timestamp is generated --->
 <cfset timestamp=DateDiff("s", "January 1 1970 00:00", DateConvert('local2UTC', Now())) >

 <!--- The following lines generate the SIM fingerprint --->
 <cf_hmac data="#loginID#^#sequence#^#timestamp#^#amount#^" key="#transactionKey#">
 <cfset fingerprint=#digest#>

 <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_amount' value='#amount#' />
 <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_description' value='#description#' />
 <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_invoice_num' value='#invoice#' />
 <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_fp_sequence' value='#sequence#' />
 <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_fp_timestamp' value='#timeStamp#' />
 <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_fp_hash' value='#fingerprint#' />
 <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_test_request' value='#testMode#' />
 <INPUT type='hidden' name='x_show_form' value='PAYMENT_FORM' />

 <CFINPUT name="button" type=button onclick="history.go(-1)" value="Edit">
 <CFINPUT type='submit' value='#label#' />     

 </CFFORM>
```

Questions:
1. Am I putting all the codes correctly? Do I have the right concept?
2. Will users see the credit card screen when they click on SUBMIT PAYMENT button?

When I tested this concept, I got a (97) error message referring to :

```
<cfset timestamp=DateDiff("s", "January 1 1970 00:00", DateConvert('local2UTC', Now())) >
```

1. How can I fix this error?
   Is it because of this error that I can't see the credit card screen?
2. Do I need to have a merchant account first and use it in my testing period?
   Is my test failed because I don't have the merchant account ?

Has anyone ever integrated SIM method from Authorize.net using ColdFusion and do not mind sharing it?
I have done so far and all I see is the error number 97

Comment: _Error 97: This transaction cannot be accepted_ - **Response Reason Code:** 97
**Response Reason Text:** This transaction cannot be accepted.
**Notes:** Applicable only to the SIM API. Fingerprints are only valid for a short period of time. This code indicates that the transaction fingerprint has expired. Taken from [Authorize.net Error 97: This transaction cannot be accepted](https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A592&actp=LIST)

Comment: Hi Miguel-F thanks for responding. In that case what am i supposed to do? sign up for sandbox again? Is my concept described above correct?

Comment: Did you read the page I referenced (the link)?  It explains the issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: As Miguel-F stated, your timestamp value is wrong. Sending the correct value will resolve the "Error 97". But it does look like you are trying to use UTC time. Output the value of: `#int(dateConvert("local2Utc", now()).getTime()/1000)#` and compare it to your `#timestamp#`. Are the values the same?

Comment: (Edit) Also, if you read the [CF sample's](http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/samplecode/) `readme.txt` file, it includes a link for an [online tool for testing timestamp values](http://developer.authorize.net/tools/responsecode97/). Nothing to do with your question, but .. a) don't post real credentials, even for test sites and b) need for `cfform`. Just use a plain hmtl `<form>`

Comment: Leigh, I linked to test the timestamp values yesterday and the result was -3800 but when I tested sample.cfm for the first time I got a successful result. Should I sign in as a new user again to get a new identity and keys?

Comment: When I just sign in to sandbox and downloaded sample.cfm codes than tested I did not get any error. That means the timestamp worked.

Comment: So it is working now? If yes, specifically what did you change or do differently? Re: Credentials, anything posted on a public site should be considered comprised. Even if you edit a post, it has already been viewed and likely archived by one more engines.

Comment: Leigh, I'm sorry if I confused you with my last comment. I meant, when I tested my sandbox early this week, I got a successful respond. When I tested again I got 97 error. So I'm wondering if I have to sign up for a new account again to get a new transaction key, a new LoginId???? and also, you did not give any comment on question regarding the way I created confirmation.cfm so I think I get the concept straighten up?

Comment: Not sure why you think a new account is the issue. Is there is something else you have not told us? The API says the usual cause of Error 97 is a bad timestamp. Did you verify yours with the online tool? You need to confirm or rule that out first.

Comment: Leigh, I mentioned about a new account was because it wasn't giving me any error. It tells me that I have no issue with the timestamp. Had the timestamp issue is due to my web server setting I would have gotten error 97 as well. My primary problem at this moment is understanding how come I don't see the credit card screen???

Comment: Are you calculating a new fingerprint each time you submit the transaction?

Comment: Honestly your responses are a little confusing :/ I have read over the comments several times and still cannot tell whether you have resolved the error described in the OP ie Error 97. Maybe rhldr will have better luck.

Comment: Leigh, I still get error 97, I don't know what to do next?

Comment: Re-read my [earlier comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650724/authorize-net-sim-method-in-coldfusion#comment40084912_25650724). I know you don't *think* your timestamp is wrong, but the API suggests otherwise. One of the first rules in troubleshooting is to assume nothing, because assumptions are often wrong. You cannot rule out timestamp as the problem until you have actually verified/proven it is correct! It does not sounds like you ever did that. So start by checking your timestamp value against their online tool.